# Python Regex char class

Tags: python, regex

**Python 3**

I have recently started reading `regex` and consider the following case :

If input is `AB` followed by `C` or `D` i want to replace it with `EF`

So, my `char class` is `[CD]` and it should be `non-capturing`.

Using the `re.sub` i come up with the following:

```
re.sub(r'AB(?:[CD])','EF',text)
```

When i run this code for input **ABCZ** i get **EFZ**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-capturing doesn't mean it's not included in the match.  It just means it's not captured as a group (so you can't use backreferences like `\1` to refer to it).

If you want to specify that `[CD]` should follow but not be included in the match, you need to use a lookahead:

```
>>> re.sub(r'AB(?=[CD])','EF','ABCZ')
'EFCZ'
```